# Проверка на упорядоченность массива алгоритмом пузырька c#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, пузырьковая-сортировка

Как сделать проверку упорядоченности массива отсортированного методом пузырька?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код.

Comment: Пузырек - это алгоритм сортировки, а не проверки упорядоченности. Чтоб проверить упорядоченность массива, достаточно один раз пройти по нему

Comment: Проверка упорядоченности никак не зависит от того, каким методом массив упорядочивался, и упорядочивался ли вообще.

Comment: Вопрос с какой стороны ни посмотри плох. И домашка, и отсуствие кода, и неполные данные в вопросе (массив строк или чисел). Проголосовал за закрытие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Речь об этом?

```
char massiv[n];
int i = 0;

for (i;i < n;i++)
{
  if (massiv[i] > massiv[i + 1])
  {
    puts("не отсортировано!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: i < n - 1 иначе здесь будет выход за границы массива massiv[i + 1]

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych, верно) я просто пример быстренько накатал.